# Getting error while adding JSON object based on condition using JQ command

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have below json input to JQ filter:

```json
[
  {
    "sn": "rv",
    "amc": {
      "ott": [
        {
          "req": [
            {
              "wc": "tc",
              "os": "des",
              "dt": "rt",
              "ip": "f"
            },
            {
              "wc": "nm",
              "os": "id",
              "dt": "s",
              "ip": "t"
            },
            {
              "wc": "rm",
              "os": "mo",
              "dt": "ts",
              "ip": "f"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "res": [
      {
        "sp": {
          "dm": "dmValue",
          "hH": "hHValue"
        },
        "des": "desval",
        "id": "1234",
        "mo": "movalur"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using below JQ syntax which reads above json data to generate output:

```
  [.[1].res as $resources 
  | (.[0].amc.ott[].req[]  
     | {(.wc): {"type": .wc,
                "value": $resources[0].[(.os)]}})] 
+
 [.[1].res as $resources 
  | {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},
    {"Mod": {"type": (.[0].amc.ott[].req[]
                      | select(.wc == "rm") 
                      | .wc),
             "value": ((.[0].amc.ott[].req[] 
                        | select(.wc == "rm") 
                        | $resources[0].[(.os)]))}}] 
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; .*$item)
```

Below is the output of above JQ command:

```json
{
  "tc": {
    "type": "tc",
    "value": "desval"
  },
  "nm": {
    "type": "nm",
    "value": "1234"
  },
  "rm": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  },
  "Column": {
    "type": "S",
    "value": "rv"
  },
  "Mod": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  }
}
```

I want to add `key3` to output only when `amc.ott.req.ip` equals to `t`, can please someone help on how to add json key
based on condition?

Below is expected output:

```json
{
  "tc": {
    "type": "tc",
    "value": "desval"
  },
  "nm": {
    "type": "nm",
    "value": "1234",
    "key3": "hHValue"
  },
  "rm": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  },
  "Column": {
    "type": "S",
    "value": "rv"
  },
  "Mod": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  }
}
```

We tried to use below JQ command:

```
[.[1].res as $resources | (.[0].amc.ott[].req[]  |
{(.wc): {"type": .wc,"value":$resources[0].[(.os)],(if (.ip=="t") then {"key3":$resources[0].sp.hH} end)}})] + 
[.[1].res as $resources | {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},{"Mod":{"type":.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | 
select(.wc == "rm") | .wc,"value":((.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | $resources[0].[(.os)]))}}] | 
reduce .[] as $item ({}; .*$item)
```

Getting below error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ':' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
{(.wc): {"type": .wc,"value":$resources[0].[(.os)],(if (.ip=="t") then {"key3":$resources[0].sp.hH} end)}})] +                                                                                                         
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 2:
{(.wc): {"type": .wc,"value":$resources[0].[(.os)],(if (.ip=="t") then {"key3":$resources[0].sp.hH} end)}})] +                                                    
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 3:
[.[1].res as $resources | {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},{"Mod":{"type":.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | .wc,"value":((.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | $resources[0].[(.os)]))}}] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .*$item)                                                                    
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 3:
[.[1].res as $resources | {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},{"Mod":{"type":.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | .wc,"value":((.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | $resources[0].[(.os)]))}}] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .*$item)                                                                    
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ']' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 3:
[.[1].res as $resources | {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},{"Mod":{"type":.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | .wc,"value":((.[0].amc.ott[].req[] | select(.wc == "rm") | $resources[0].[(.os)]))}}] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .*$item)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
jq: 5 compile errors
exit status 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
.[1].res[0] as $resources
| .[0].amc.ott[].req as $reqs
| ($reqs | map({(.wc): ({"type": .wc, "value":$resources[.os]} + (if .ip == "t" then {"key3": $resources.sp.hH} else null end))}))
+ [ {"Column" : {"type":"S","value":.[0].sn}},
    {"Mod": $reqs[] | select(.wc == "rm") | {"type": .wc,"value": $resources[.os]}}
  ]
| add
```

Output:

```json
{
  "tc": {
    "type": "tc",
    "value": "desval"
  },
  "nm": {
    "type": "nm",
    "value": "1234",
    "key3": "hHValue"
  },
  "rm": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  },
  "Column": {
    "type": "S",
    "value": "rv"
  },
  "Mod": {
    "type": "rm",
    "value": "movalur"
  }
}
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/wGwZnWXrbgZ).